# xml to csv converter with php

Tags: php, xml, csv, converters

I need to convert this xml in csv format.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <categories>
     <0>
       <id>1</id>
       <status>1</status>
       <name>Mobile Accessories</name>
       <code>006</code>
     </0>
     <1>
       <id>2</id>
       <status>1</status>
       <name>Computer &amp; Networking</name>
       <code>005</code>
     </1>
     <0>
       <id>100027</id>
       <parentId>1</parentId>
       <status>1</status>
       <name>Cover</name>
       <code>001</code>
     </0>
    </categories>
```

The problem is that the index is not

```
<category>
```

,but a number as in the example, which sometimes repeats itself (eg twice repeated index <0>).

How can I do to convert csv file with a php script?